# Как сделать несколько фоновых изображений с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать, например, три фоновых рисунка, чтоб кусок был внизу (не повторялся), в середине (чтоб удлинялся в зависимости от размера контента) и сверху, статичное фоновое изображение. Верстка DIV-ами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю три дива вложенных сделать (здесь 50px - высота фоновых картинок верха и низа)

```css
#content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#bg1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: transparent url('/images/bg-top.png') left top no-repeat;
}

#bg2 {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background: transparent url('/images/bg-bottom.png') right bottom no-repeat;
}

#content {
  background: #ffffff url('/images/bg-middle.png') center center repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg1">
  <div id="bg2">
    <div id="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="body"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Как-то так. Ну и закрепить хоть фиксировано, хоть %. Вроде ничего сложного и должно работать.